# Validate ValidationGroup

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery, validation

I have a button on which I wish to validate a specific `ValidationGroup` in ASP.NET. This button is not a server control, but a standard `a` tag with an `onclick` event on.

I have multiple validation groups on this page, so by calling `Page_ClientValidate()` is not enough, as the other validators will kick in as well.

If your answer requires JQuery, its fine.

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you just need to pass the validation group name to `Page_ClientValidate`.

```
Page_ClientValidate('myGroup');
```